# How to use prebuilt FFmpeg in Android Studio

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk

I'm sure this is a very basic question but since this is the my first time messing around with the NDK, a lot of thing is still very unclear to me.

**Use case:**

- I'm trying to develop a video scrubbing feature so fast and accurate frame seeking is crucial. I've tried most of the available players out there but the performance is still not up to my demand. That's why I'm going down the FFmpeg route.
- Basically, what I'm looking for is [FFmpeg input seeking](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking). I've tried [WrtingMinds' ffmpeg-android-java](http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/). However it is a file based implementation which means the `out.jpg` need to be written to external memory and read back which has a big hit on performance (roughly 1000 milliseconds for 1 seek).
- That's why I'm trying to built my own FFmpeg player to do the input seeking in JNI and push back the `byte[]` to be displayed in Java.

**Question:** After a lot of struggling with the NDK, I've managed to set it up and successfully calling the JNI method from my Java code. The structure is as below:

```
MyApp
  -app
  -MyFFmpegPlayer
    -build
    -libs
    -src
      -main
        -java
          -com.example.myffmpegplayer
            +HelloJNI.java
        -jni
          +MyFFmpegPlayer.c
```

After some fail attempt to build FFmpeg on Windows, I've decided to use [WritingMinds](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android/releases/tag/v0.3.4) prebuilt FFmpeg. However, after extraction they just come up as plain `ffmpeg` files (not `.so` file) so I don't really know how to use these.

It would be a great gratitude, if someone can just chime in and give me a good starting point for my next step.

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: imo - you may be better off if you remove windows from the picture. Implement a VM. Learn how to use ARMV7 cross-toolchain on your VM. Build ffmpeg-for-armv7A in your VM. Go back to how you were calling ffmpeg.so on Android-NDK. If you r on Android studio then also keep up with http://ph0b.com/new-android-studio-ndk-support/

Comment: Thanks you so much for your reply @Robert Rowntree. I do indeed come across your link before, that's how I set up the experimental and stable Gradle working together. I also understand that building ffmpeg on Windows is very difficult but due to some work constraints, I can't really install a Linux for now. That's why I turn to the pre built route. Are you suggesting that I should just ditch this pre built FFmpeg and built my own version?

Comment: given your requirements.... working with some third party ffmpeg prebuilt has low probability of bug-free success. if buggy then what???  working with your own ffmpeg build is very timeconsuming but puts you in position with much better chance of resolve bugs that arise.  building ffmpeg on windows goes against convention... rather , learn how to use VM on windows so that you can just build like everyone else builds....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to answer my own question which I should change to "How to build FFmpeg and use it with Android Studio", I have create a detail [step-by-step](https://gist.github.com/vxhviet/0a4e48f903bf9b99a7bd7fbb61a206eb) instruction that's working for me (at **May 24th 2016**).

Sorry I can't post the whole instruction here as it is very long, plus it is easier for me to keep 1 source of information up-to-date.

I hope this can help someone as I know there is way too much confusing and contradicting information regarding this topic out there.